# Custom Taxonomy registered with multiple custom posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am using a custom taxonomy location with two custome post types (Place and Resorts)

I have three issues here

1)Count shows sum of both CPT's on the taxonomy page

How to show the counts separately ?

2)I want hide the category metabox in one of the CPT's

How to do it?

3)show_ui false in one custom post type

```
register_taxonomy(locations', array('place','resorts'), array(
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'labels'        => array(
        'name'                      => __('Locations','tfuse'),
        'singular_name'             => __('Location','tfuse'),
        'search_items'              => __('Search Locations','tfuse'),
        'all_items'                 => __('All Locations','tfuse'),
        'parent_item'               => __('Parent Location','tfuse'),
        'parent_item_colon'         => __('Parent Location:','tfuse'),
        'edit_item'                 => __('Edit Location','tfuse'),
        'update_item'               => __('Update Location','tfuse'),
        'add_new_item'              => __('Add New Location','tfuse'),
        'new_item_name'             => __('New Location Name','tfuse'),
        'choose_from_most_used'     => __('Choose from the most used locations','tfuse'),
        'separate_items_with_commas'=> __('Separate location with commas','tfuse')
    ),
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'query_var'     => true
));
```

Comment: Maybe you could clarify some more, for example 1) Which count, where shown? 3) Do you mean that you don't want that taxonomy  show up in one of your cpt or one cpt not be visible in the admin?

Comment: Count shown in the taxonomy page and hide the taxonomy in one of the cpt